# Django Register Page refill input data after site reload

Tags: python, html, django

Im looking for a solution to refill my select fields of a Register Page after a site reload, if the user has given invalid data and should correct the problem. The use of the Django Template works fine on the input field. There I can just give the value of the tag a django variable and when the variable is filled it gets displayed. But on the birthdate selections i have to use an if statement for every option that sets the select attribute selected="selected". And this for 31 days, 12 months and around 90 years. So there are 133 if statements and I think this is slowing down the backend unecesserily.

I try to avoid java script and I have some safety concerns about window.sessionStorage so I would rather use my way with Django Templates. Do you know a more elegant solution for refilling a select field?

the function:

```py
def registerPage(request):

    context = {}  #needed for the value rebuild when user has to reload the register page
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        first_name = request.POST.get('fname')
        last_name = request.POST.get('lname')
        password1 = request.POST.get('password1')
        password2 = request.POST.get('password2')
        email = request.POST.get('user_email')
        birth_day = request.POST.get('bday')
        birth_month = request.POST.get('bmonth')
        birth_year = request.POST.get('byear')
        gender_type = request.POST.get('gender_type')
    
        context = {'fname':first_name, 'lname':last_name, 'user_email':email,     'bday':birth_day, 'bmonth':birth_month, 'byear':birth_year, 'gender_type':gender_type}

       
           # further processing ...
              

        return redirect('userlogin')


    # on first siteload context is empty and so all the inputs
    # after first POST request the context is filled 

    return render(request, 'users/register.html', context)
```

my template:

```html
<input class="fnameinput" type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="{{fname}}" placeholder="Vorname" required>


<div class="monthselect">
    <select name="bmonth" id="bmonth" value="{{bmonth}}" required>
        <optgroup label="Month">
            <option {% if bmonth == "01" %} selected="selected" {% endif %} value="01">Jan </option>
            <option {% if bmonth == "02" %} selected="selected" {% endif %} value="02">Feb.</option>
            <option {% if bmonth == "03" %} selected="selected" {% endif %} value="03">Mar.</option>
            <option {% if bmonth == "04" %} selected="selected" {% endif %} value="04">Apr.</option>
            <option {% if bmonth == "05" %} selected="selected" {% endif %} value="05">May</option>
            <option {% if bmonth == "06" %} selected="selected" {% endif %} value="06">Jun.</option>
            <option {% if bmonth == "07" %} selected="selected" {% endif %} value="07">Jul.</option>
            <option {% if bmonth == "08" %} selected="selected" {% endif %} value="08">Aug.</option>
            <option {% if bmonth == "09" %} selected="selected" {% endif %} value="09">Sep.</option>
            <option {% if bmonth == "10" %} selected="selected" {% endif %} value="10">Oct.</option>
            <option {% if bmonth == "11" %} selected="selected" {% endif %} value="11">Nov.</option>
            <option {% if bmonth == "12" %} selected="selected" {% endif %} value="12">Dec.</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>
</div>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like creating a list in the view and iterating over it in the template.

```py
def registerPage(request):
    ...
    context['year_list'] = list(range(1, 91))

    # for months, we have the number and also the label/name
    context['month_list'] = [
        (i+1, s)
        for i, s in enumerate(['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar'])]

    context['day_list'] = list(range(1, 32))
    ...
```

and in the template:

```html
<div class="monthselect">
    <select name="bmonth" id="bmonth" value="{{bmonth}}" required>
        <optgroup label="Month">
        {% for e in month_list %}
            <option {% if bmonth == e.0 %} selected="selected" {% endif %} value="{{ e.0 }}">{{ e.1 }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
        </optgroup>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah thanks this is very nice to reduce the code. But doesnt increase this the server processing more when he have to build the lists and run through the for do loops and check the if statement instead of running only through the big code block and check for every line if the attribute should be set?

Comment: @AugustGraf a few if-statements won't slow down the template processing very much.

Comment: If you are really concerned about performance then use `<input type="date">` instead of `<select>` (and the browser displays a datetime-picker for that field automatically) to skip all the extra rendering/template processing

Comment: Thats a nice solution to! Thanks. For other people reading this, its maybe an important info that Safari doesnt support input type="date"